# Where am I going wrong when evaluating this integral using trigonometric substitution?

Tags: calculus

$$\int { \frac { 4 }{ 1+16x^{ 2 } }  } dx$$

Steps I took:

$$4\int { \frac { \sec ^{ 2 }{ \theta  }  }{ 1+\tan ^{ 2 }{ \theta  }  } d\theta  } $$

$$4\int { \frac { \sec ^{ 2 }{ \theta  }  }{ \sec ^{ 2 }{ \theta  }  } d\theta  } $$

$$4\int { d\theta  } $$

$$4\arctan { x } +C$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your substitution of $\theta=4\tan^{-1}(x)$ in the final step is wrong

Let $$4x=\tan \theta \implies \theta =\tan^{-1}(4x) \ \text{&}\ \ 4dx=\sec^2\theta d\theta$$
$$\int \frac{4}{1+16x^2}dx=\int \frac{4}{1+(4x)^2}dx$$
$$=\int \frac{\sec^2\theta d\theta }{1+\tan^2\theta}=\int \frac{\sec^2\theta  }{\sec^2\theta}d\theta$$
$$=\int d\theta$$$$=\theta+C$$$$=\color{red}{\tan^{-1}(4x)+C} $$

Comment: What happen to the 4 in the numerator?

Comment: alright, notice we let $4x=\tan \theta\iff 4dx=\sec^2\theta d\theta $ In numerator $4dx$ is substituted by $sec^2\theta d\theta$

Comment: So, $dx\quad =\quad \frac { 1 }{ 4 } \sec ^{ 2 }{ \theta  } d\theta $

Comment: yes, if you substitute $dx=\frac{1}{4}\sec^2\theta d\theta$ then we get $$\int \frac{4}{1+\tan^2\theta}\frac{1}{4}\sec^2\theta d\theta=\int \frac{\sec^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}d\theta$$

Answer (score 2):

easier way
$$\int { \frac { 4 }{ 1+16x^{ 2 } }  } dx=\int { \frac { 4 }{ 1+(4x)^{ 2 } }  } dx$$
Now use $u=4x$ so $du=4dx$
$$\int { \frac { 1 }{ 1+u^{ 2 } }  } dx=arctan u=arctan 4x $$